# How to add a word to the end of the String

Tags: iphone, ios, string, url

I want to add some words to the end of the string. Example:
We have a string: `NSString *str = @"http://xxxx.com/";`

And after few commands I want to add some words to that string and make it something like this:

```
@"http://example.com/api/get_data"
```

Should I use MutableString?

Comment: Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html.. It is not difficult to figure it out

Comment: if it is difficult for me? if i just want to learn? if i cannot figure it out from apple developer library? you have to be more patient. you have to be more thoughtful about your customers, if they just want to learn? my question is not a spam or is not an ad. SO IT. IS. JUST. A. FREAKING. QUESTION

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I have just given you a link and wanted to say that if you read it, it is not difficult to figure it out. I never commented on your learning methods or anything.

Comment: oh man, i did not meant you. i meant people who made my question off topic, and blocked my permission to ask question. you are good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create new string like this:

```
NSString *str = @"http://xxxx.com/";
NSString *newString = [str stringByAppendingString:@"otherString"];
```

If you want to add string to that specific string variable than use NSMutableString:

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxx.com/"];
[str appendString:@"other string"];
```

Comment: You mean [str stringByAppendingString:@"otherString"]; ?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableString *myString = @"http://xxxx.com/";
[myString appendString:@"api/get_data"];
```

Use `NSMutableString`. This prevents the need for extra new temp strings.

Comment: This won't work. Try it in xcode.

Comment: Apart from the spurious `*` in the second line: For a *mutable* string use `appendString` instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: Oh! yes the syntax is incorrect, correcting it...

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
NSString *main = @"http://xxxx.com/";
NSString *sub = @"thisIsword";

NSString *newString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",main,sub];
```